# Python: on linux, subprocess.Popen() works weird with shell = True

Tags: python

If I execute following python code on Windows:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen( [ 'python', 'foo' ], shell = True ).communicate()
```

I got error written into stdout, as expected:

```
python: can't open file 'foo': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

But if i execute same code on linux (ubuntu, OSX - any) I got interactive python REPL started instead of this text! Like this:

```
user@debian:~/Documents$ python test.py
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jab 2 2013, 16:53:07)
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information
>>>
```

Why such strange behaviour? executing python interpreter with argument ('foo') must put it into evaluation mode on all platforms, not into REPL mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is spelled out in the documentation:

> The shell argument (which defaults to False) specifies whether to use the shell as the program to execute. **If shell is True, it is recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence.**
>
> **On Unix with shell=True**, the shell defaults to /bin/sh. If args is a string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell. This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be when typed at the shell prompt. This includes, for example, quoting or backslash escaping filenames with spaces in them. *If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string*, and **any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself.**

(emphasis mine)